# PathParam value null in Jersey web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I'm new to web services and writing code to call Jersey web service in Android. But I'm getting null as parameter values of PathParam. 
Please help me out in getting what's wrong with my code.

Here is the code for **web service call** in Android:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);  

httpPost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");  
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();  

try {  
   data.put("email_id", strEmailId);  
   data.put("password", strPassword);  
   Log.d("1", data.toString());  
   HttpEntity entity;  
   StringEntity s = new StringEntity(data.toString());  
   entity = s;  
   httpPost.setEntity(entity);  
   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);  
}
```

This is the **web service code**:

```
@POST  
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
@Path("/dbconnect")  
public String connectToDbTest(@PathParam("email_id") String email_id,@PathParam("password") String password) {  
   System.out.println(email_id+" "+password);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the use of 
    StringEntity 
class, but on the server code, if you are using Path parameters, the parameters should be declared in the template before they are used. e.g.

```
    @Path("/dbconnect/{email_id}/{password}")
```

and the URL received on server should be

```
    protocol://server/context/dbconnect/email@id.com/password
```

Though it is a very bad idea to pass password through url, but functionally, it will work.

Comment: But i am not passing value in path of url, i am passing the value in request body. So i can't make it like @Path("/dbconnect/{email_id}/{password}")

Comment: mitratul answer it's correct. For receiving the body and keeping your actual path, change the signature of your method in order to receive the JSON content: `public String connectToDbTest(String content) { ... }` (drop the @PathParam's because they are used wrong). From the content string you can manually extract your variables or use a framework like JAXB that automatically converts the JSON string into a model object.